# Перевести плагин Contact Form 7 для wp

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Как можно перевести (локализовать) плагин Contact Form 7 для wordpress на русский?

При добавлении новой формы не появляется варианта выбора языка. 
`define ('WPLANG', 'ru_Ru');` в wp-config.php тоже не дает результата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два способа. Это сама папка плагина, там  вы можете поменять строки такого формата __()
Частично они в админке.
Так же хорошо использовать WPML плагин.

Comment: т.е. самой перевести строки, либо использовать доп. плагин для перевода.

Comment: Да, как правило, лично у меня софт, который делает *.ro и *.mo файлы глючит, да и не всегда работает(что нужно выяснять в программе)

Answer (score 1):

И `.mo` и `.po` файлы с переводом можно скачать здесь - https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/stable/ru/default

Их надо поместить в папку `wp-content/languages/plugins` с названиями `contact-form-7-ru_RU.mo` и `contact-form-7-ru_RU.po`

Я измененила язык сайта на русский в настройках (`Настройки - Общие`), удалила и заново установила плагин, и эти файлы появились сами.

Answer (score 0):

Когда столкнулся у себя, долго искал, а оказалось что просто во вкладке "Уведомления при отправке формы" конкретной формы фразы были на англицком. Перекинул русские из другой формы